# AndroidStudioでツールバーにロゴを表示する方法

Tags: android, java, android-studio, xml

サービスのロゴをツールバーに表示したいのですが、できません。。
画像自体はres/drawableにpngで入っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#fdaea4"


        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.PonyLogo);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

警告のマーク等も出ていないのですが、間違っている箇所があればご教示いただけると嬉しいです。
Version 3.0.1です。

Comment: 質問が解決した場合、回答の横のチェックマークを押すことで回答を承認することができます。必須ではありませんが、よろしければお願いいたします :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ツールバーをアクションバーとして扱うのであれば、(可能な限り)アクションバーとして扱った方がいいですよ。

Toolbar#setLogoではなく、ActionBar#setLogoで指定すればできました。

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.PolyLogo);
```